How viable are index funds for non-retirement investing?
I am a graduate student in the USA and therefore have no 401k. I am investing some money in a Roth IRA and was wondering what to do with the remaining. I have already taken care of my emergency fund. I am thinking of purchasing the same index funds as the Roth IRA, but for a regular brokerage. How viable is that? Since I am on the younger side, I think I can invest this amount for longer periods.
By viable, what could the downsides be of buying index funds from a non-IRA account?

Would the taxes be extremely high for dividends or when I actually sell?

Would a CD/bonds be a better option if I want to move the money within half a decade?

Can something else go wrong?



There are no downsides. Index funds are index funds, and are a perfectly reasonable way to do diversified investing. Both my retirement account (a 401k) and my "normal" savings (other than bank accounts) are in a mix of index funds.
A major advantage of index funds over other kinds of mutual funds is that the fees are generally remarkably low, and since those fees subtract directly from your rate of return reducing them is a win. Often it's enough of an advantage to make index funds perform as well as, or better than, managed funds when looking at real return.
As with any investment, if it isn't done through a tax-advantaged account, you will have to report dividends and capital gains on your income tax, at least in the US. Capital gains outside a 401k, ira, or equivalent, are taxed when you actually sell fund shares to pull money back out of the account to buy something else (either another investment or something else you need cash for). Dividends, even if reinvested, are considered income and taxed with the year that they are paid in. Note that this is true of most kinds of investments, not just mutual funds, and not just index funds.

Also. worth mentioning since the OP asked, both capital gains and dividends for long term holdings are taxed at significantly lower rates than salary income.

"Dividends, even if reinvested, are considered income and taxed with the year that they are paid in" It's not that simple. Qualified dividends are taxed more like capital gains.

@JimmyJames: Granted. And international funds may have further details  None of it hard to deal with, in my experience, especially if you use a tax prep program.


Since, I am on the younger side, I think I can invest this amount for
longer periods.

So if the need for the money is many years or even decades away, then investing in stock/mutual funds/ETFs is a reasonable thing to do.
If the term is shorter like saving money to buy a car or as a down payment on a house then investing in stocks/mutual funds/ETFs may not be the right thing to do.
The advantage of an index fund is that it captures the broad part of the market it is tracking, with low expenses because the research costs are need to decide what to invest in.

I am thinking of purchasing purchasing the same index funds as Roth
IRA, but for a regular brokerage. How viable is that?

I would go so far as saying if the goal is to not sell for a long time, then the index fund makes even more sense in the non-retirement account.
If your goal is to be able to re-balance the investment mix periodically that is easily done within the IRA or Roth IRA. Selling one fund to buy another has no tax impact. If you do this in a taxable account then it will have tax implications.
Now on to your questions.


Would the taxes be extremely high for dividends or when I actually sell?


If you hold the fund long enough the dividends and capital gains are taxed at lower rates than ordinary income. Even an index fund can have dividends and capital gains. But depending on your total income the rates can be significantly lower.


Would a CD/bonds be a better option if I want to move the money within half a decade.


If the money is needed in 5 years you have to decide what happens if the market drops just before you need the money. Can you wait a year or two to makeup for the losses? Or is the money need at a very specific time?
If a badly timed market will destroy your plans then maybe the CD makes more sense. Index fund vs actively managed fund are not different enough that one would be better to protect you in this situation.


Can something else go wrong?


All investments have risk. All investments have costs.  You still have to pick which index. There are broad indexes, industry specific indexes, regional indexes. There are also indexes linked to bonds.

Index funds tend to have lower capital gains distributions. They generally only need to sell shares in the underlying stocks when the composition of the index changes.

You specifically mention index funds here.  And while I don't want to get pedantic about terminology, you should realize that, outside of a tax-sheltered account such as an IRA, there's no good reason to be buying mutual funds.  Pretty much any kind of mutual fund you would like has an equivalent exchange traded fund (ETF).  ETFs are much more tax efficient due to the 'redemption in kind' structure.  Aside from that, they are very easy to buy and sell with no transaction fee at many major brokerages.  Mutual fund purchases and/or sales often have pretty large fees associated with them.
Other answers have already mentioned the impact of fees on long-term investments. As with indexed mutual funds, index-based ETFs tend to have lower fees (sometimes even lower than the equivalent mutual fund) and make a good option for the core of your long-term investments.

I will comment on the tax aspects.  You may want to seek a fund that pays out very little in they way of income.  Long term capital gains and qualified dividends are okay to be paid out.  You get a significant exemption from paying taxes on these.
You don't want to have a fund that pays out large short term capital gains or non-qualified dividends as these will be taxed at your marginal rate.
As I approach retirement, it is almost better to have money in a brokerage account rather than a Roth.
